# Convert Perl MD5 Digest and Create to PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, perl, powershell

I am trying to convert the following in Perl to PowerShell, I am stuck on the MD5 Digest and Create.

```
timestamp=1283473470
key='this-is-my-key'
secret='secret'
perl -e  "use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex); print md5_hex('$key' . '$secret' . $timestamp);"
```

For testing purposes I am setting the time stamp to a static number. That way I can compare what Perl says and what PowerShell says. I'v tried out a few MD5 and [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm] attempts but so far I have manged to little more than confuse myself.

In Perl....

```
> perl -e  "use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex); print md5_hex('this-is-my-key' . 'secret' . '1283473470');"
> a135923fb8e579463f312b69528d243c
```

In PowerShell

```
>_ 'this-is-my-key.secret.1283473470' | Get-Hash


Algorithm: MD5


Path       :
HashString : 04BF4CA4BF3E34C83F0B11970205580D
```

Comment: Almost every time I have to answer this question, the problem is that the person is supplying different strings in each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Get-Hash` cmdlet in the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).  Give it a try.

```
PS> 'this-is-my-key.secret.1283473470' | Get-Hash


Algorithm: MD5


Path       :
HashString : 04BF4CA4BF3E34C83F0B11970205580D
```

or if the string needs to be interpreted as ASCII:

```
PS> $foo = 'THIS-is-my-keysecret1283473470'
PS> $foo.ToLower() | Get-Hash -StringEncoding ascii


Algorithm: MD5


Path       :
HashString : A135923FB8E579463F312B69528D243C
```

Comment: lol I was throwing all sorts of things at get-hash and it never occurred to me to pipe the string to it. trying now.

Comment: Darn! I was so hopeful. They don't match. Perl gives: a135923fb8e579463f312b69528d243c

Comment: What does the perl dot syntax `'str' . 'str'` do here?

Comment: Looks like they do a combine. So the command should be:
'this-is-my-keysecret1283473470' | Get-Hash -StringEncoding ascii

Comment: Hmm.. can't seem to pipe variables to Get-hash... also looks like I'll have to convert to lowercase.

Comment: Hmm, works for me - see updated answer.  How are you attempting to pipe the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Alright here is is, in large part due to Keith Hill's direction.
Mind you in this case I found it best to specify [string] everywhere, this is more or less just based on being consistent it only needs to be specified in two of the lines.

```
[string]$timestamp=1283473470
[string]$key='this-is-my-key'
[string]$secret='secret'
[string]$string=$key+$secret+$timestamp
[string]$CAPhash=$string | Get-Hash -StringEncoding ascii
[string]$hash=$CAPhash.ToLower()
$hash
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to combine the last two lines into one. For the moment I am pleased with what I have.